# Installing The Stress Terminal UI, s-tui

Tags: 18.04, stress-testing

From reading some other threads on here, I learned about the existence of s-tui.  Here is some more information about it
https://github.com/amanusk/s-tui#simple-installation

However, when I type the command 
sudo pip install s-tui

terminal says
sudo: pip: command not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the `pip` tool for python 2 with

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

then you use that command of yours!

Answer (score 0):

I know the original question is for 18.04. But as this question is still on top search engines results:

Since Ubuntu 18.10, `s-tui` is available from default repositories:

```
sudo apt install s-tui
```