# Live Boot USB including repair/testing tools and S-TUI

Tags: live-usb, tools

I am seeking to create a live USB boot disk that includes various system repair and testing tools.
I am most interested in one called S-TUI.
I am just having trouble finding something current and suitable to do this.
Hoping someone here may be able to provide some suggestions for this, and point me in the right direction.
Thanks.

Comment: You can try `sudo apt install s-tui` after creating a persistent Ubuntu USB

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/q/1108987/43926 You can also install it on a Full install USB https://askubuntu.com/q/1403792/43926